# How create checkstyle rule for final values

Tags: android, checkstyle

I would like create a checkstyle rule for constants. My problem is how I can set the scope in this rule. Let see it:

I have this code:

```
public class foo {

    //all are memeberName for checkstyle
    private final int NUMBER = 10; // violation is member
    private int mNumber = 3;

    private void bar(){
        final String text = "foo"; // violation is final
        String txt = "example";
    }
}
```

checkstyle.xml

```
<!-- final var -->
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
        <property name="format" value="^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9\_]*$" />
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
            value="violation is final." />
    </module>
<module name="MemberName">
        <property name="format" value="^[m][A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
            value="violation is member." />
    </module>
```

How could I use member rule excet final var and add this rule to class constants?

This is my checkstyle dependence: checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:8.26'

thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be this check is the one you are looking for
https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/naming/ConstantNameCheck.html

Comment: Thank you for your answerd. It is not I am looking for. With this rule, when a constant is a member too checkstyle take member rule not constant rule

Comment: Other options are:
1. Try to use regexp check, e.g.https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_regexp.html
2. Make constants static (do not cover all cases)
3. Open new issue in checkstyle repo

Comment: regexp could be a solution but I still without control the scope. Thanks you